# how to pass default value="1" in input type text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem i'm facing is that value is not passing to the default value to "1" even i've passed the value="1" inside input elements.

```
 <Form onFinish={this.onFormSubmit}>
   <div class="row">
    
    <Form.Item name="product">
        <input type="text" value="1" disabled />
    </Form.Item>

    </div>

<button type="submit" value="submit" class="site-btn">Submit Now</button>

</Form>
```

Comment: Try to use [`defaultValue`](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) instead of `value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using [Ant-D Form](https://ant.design/components/form/), so it would be helpful to actually read the API for the component. From what I know, the ant design form behaves like most other third-party form components and supports two main ways of providing initial values to the fields:

1. `initialValues` prop of `<Form>`:
   accepts an object where keys describe the `Item's` name and value the `initialValue <string>` for the field
2. `initialValue` prop of `<Form.Item>`:
   accepts `initialValue` as a string

Therefore the implementation in your case could look like this:

```
<Form
    onFinish={this.onFormSubmit}
    initialValues={{
        product: '1'
    }}
>
    <div class="row">
        <Form.Item name="product">
            <input type="text" disabled />
        </Form.Item>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="site-btn">Submit Now</button>
</Form>
```